# Get a list of connections in control panel to ComboBox

Tags: vb.net

How to get a list of connections in control panel and output them to a combobox?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GetAllNetworkInterfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim ni = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces
```

To filter those listed in network connections:

```
Dim niEthernet = ni.Where(Function(x) x.NetworkInterfaceType =
                          Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
```

Regarding putting these in a combobox, you need to decide how they should appear. If it's just a connection name per combobox entry, you can do it without data binding:

```
For Each i In niEthernet
  ComboBox1.Items.Add(i.Name)
Next
```

Or with data binding:

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = niEthernet.Select(Function(x) x.Name).ToList()
```